# Issue with forms authentication not working remotely

Tags: iis-7, location, forms-authentication, asp.net-4.0

We have an issue where forms authentication works correctly locally when run from Visual Studio but not remotely from a server running IIS 7.  We have also determined that it works correctly on the remote server if we browse to the local site from the server.  More specifically, when logging in using the login screen sometimes we are taken into the application and sometimes we are redirected back to the login screen.  For the times when we are taken in we are at a one click maximum situation where, if we click on any item inside the site, we are immediately sent back out to the login page.  We are using .NET 4.0  We are using location to set permissions on a per directory basis in the web.config:

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

We have tested that the issue must have something to do with this setting because as soon as we change deny users="*" to allow users="*" it works when testing remotely to the test server.  Again, the issue only occurs when promoting to the test environment and testing remotely and works perfectly when running in Visual Studio or when browsing to the localhost site from the remote server.  My guess is an IIS 7 setting but we have played around with a few of the settings to no success.

Answer (score 0):

It has a simple solution. in your IIS 7 click on the top most node(Your server node) then click on "Modules" in IIS part of the home page.

Double click Default Authentication and uncheck the "Invoke only for ..." option
Double click Forms Authentication and uncheck the "Invoke only for ..." option

your forms authentication will work perfectly